# How do I know which material is assigned to a part of the mesh

Tags: materials

Is there a way to know which material a part of the mesh is assigned to?

We know that we can select a material and click on `Select` to select all the parts of the object that use this material but is the other way possible. Like if I select some faces, how can I know which material they are using?

I'm aware of the trivial method that involves selecting each material and clicking on the `Select` button to check if the desired set of faces are selected but it can be really long if we have many materials so I want to know if there is another way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you select a face, the slot it uses is selected in the Properties editor. So that tells you what slot any single face is using.

Comment: I'm also aware of that but sometimes, for some reason, it doesn't do that.

Comment: Got it. It works only when selecting a single face, I think it's the active face's material slot that gets selected, it doesn't work when I select more than one face, even when they use the same material. Thank you for the precision.

Comment: One workaround is to use the Material's "Viewport Display" color to give each material a different color.  In solid mode the individual faces will show up in the color assigned to the material.

Comment: @MartyFouts, yes, it would be better done each time you create a material, if you haven't done that and you have an object with 20+ materials, it's gonna be fancy :D